# Bold a specific text within a range (broken up into multiple cells)

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am building a template in Excel and I would like the phrase "6. Description Summary:" to be bold using VBA. The cell the phrase is located is not static so the code should be able to pick up the phrase anywhere within the range.

Currently the code makes the whole range A1:G100 bold

Here is what I have tried:

```
 Set BoldRange = Range("A1:G100").Find("6. Description Summary:")
        If Not (BoldRange Is Nothing) Then
            BoldRange.Font.Bold = True
        End If
```

Would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is a way to edit this code to make it bold only the specified text.

Update: The text is broken up into multiple cells so I am actually looking to only bold the specified string.

Comment: That's what the code does. Perhaps you need to unbold the whole block at the start?

Comment: How would I unbold the whole block at the start?

Comment: `Range("A1:G100").font.bold=false`

Answer (score 0):

The code does what you want, I checked it myself. Set BoldRange = Range("A1:G100").Find("6. Description Summary:") returns the range where the string is found, and that is the only cell that is turned to bold. Check in your code if you are not manipulting the range somewhre else where you might be changing the whole range to bold.
Below the code I used, just in case it helps (just yours into a Sub()):

`Sub FindAndBold()
    Set BoldRange = Range("A1:G100").Find("6. Description Summary:")
    If Not (BoldRange Is Nothing) Then
        BoldRange.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: I just reviewed the code, what if the specified text is broken up into multiple cells? Would that require editing the formula? Perhaps this formula bolds the whole cell it finds the text in.

Comment: The code bolds all the text contained in the cell. However in the question is said that the problem is that the code makes the whole range A1:G100 bold, which as far as I checked is not the case. Regarding the text being broken up into multiple cells, that topic is not asked in the question neither. So I dont see the point of those two issues brought to the discussion, as they are beyond the scope of the question

Comment: I have found out the text is broken up into multiple cells which is why it is bolding the whole range so now I can update my question.

Comment: That information should have provided at the start. That said, it still doesn't explain why the whole range is bolded as the boldrange would be nothing.

Comment: I checked that, and if the text is broke up into multiple cells the string "6. Description Summary:" is not found so nothing is bold....

Comment: Apologies. I did not think of it when I wrote the question. I was still brainstorming and realized that is a piece of critical information.

Comment: On my Excel, the whole range is being bolded. It is a merged cell which contains multiple cells. Have you merged the cell Rusty?

Comment: Y did (once you told me), thought that could be quite relevant, but it only does bold the cell (or cells if combined) where the text is found. I have tried merging cells horizontally and vertically. Nevermind...